# Multiply and divide $1 in .gnu file simultaneously

Tags: gnuplot, using

Can someone tell me how I can simultaneously multiply and divide $1 in gnuplot, like I have divided $1 previously using following script without rewrite data file.

splot 'dssp.gnu' using ($1*2) : ($2) : ($3)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want

Comment: @Christoph Actually in dssp.gnu file column 1 ($1) is number of frame to convert it in time (ps) I have to first multiply $1 by 2 and then I want to divide it by 1000 to covert time from ps to ns.

Comment: `using ($1 * 2 / 1000.0):2:3`

Comment: @Christoph I have already tried script which you have suggested above but it didn't work. I got blank jpg file. Actually in original dssp.gnu file, x axis is number of frame but I wanted to convert it in png in which x axis is time (ps) without manually editing. Using command convert my large data file column in from frame to time by multiplying 2. But now I want to convert this time in ns without write date date file and want to save it in picture format.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive